# C++, Reading a space delimited line but the \n is included

Tags: c++, newline, space, delimited

So basically I am trying to read the line:

```
Darth_Vader 100 100 60 40
```

each thing has to go into its own variable. Everything works fine except the variable which should hold the value 40 at the end does not do so but has the value -858993460.

Here is the relevant code:

```
void Jedi::inputData(istream& inputStream)
{
    string nameText, maxHPText, currHPText, atkBonusText, defBonusText;
    inputStream >> nameText >> maxHPText >> currHPText >> atkBonusText >> defBonusText;

    Jedi::setName(nameText);
    Jedi::setMaxHealth(stoi(maxHPText));
    Jedi::setCurrHealth(stoi(currHPText));
    Jedi::setAttackBonus(stoi(atkBonusText));
    Jedi::setDefenseBonus(stoi(defBonusText));
}
```

How do I get the inputStream to ignore the new line, grab the 40, and then go to the next line for the next time the function is called?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: have you tried using a `getline()`?

Comment: Yes I have. I even tried accepting the last piece of data as new line delimited but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: elaborate more please, we need more details to the question. may be try posting more part of code too.

Comment: What part should I post? Do you want the class files? The driver that tests the class?

Comment: Were the instructions in the link I provided not clear?

Comment: Try throwing `std::endl` at the end of the in stream.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nRG5AmGca7rdgyNq). The last value was `40`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try getline(), then trim() on the fetched line.

Now with the line as a std::string, you can use string tokenizer to fetch each "word", and convert those values that have to be numeric to integers using atoi or a library function, like `boost::lexical_cast<int>(strValue)`